# finf if the limit exists for a 2 variable functions

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^2 \cos y}{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Cannot seem to understand how the answer is $.5$ , I tried to use squeeze with $0<\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}<1$ and I got $1$ so that didn't work for squeeze and I tried approaching from different paths and that also gave me an answer dependent on the slop so that also didn't work. what am I not seeing?

Comment: I took the chance of LaTeXifying your post.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$, where $t\rightarrow0$, then we obtain $f(x,y)\rightarrow1$

and for $(x,y)=(t^2,t)$, where $t\rightarrow0$,  we obtain $f(x,y)\rightarrow0$,

which says the the limit does not exist.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Thank you for confirming that the limit does not exist.

Comment: You are welcome,  Andrew!